# Check Attribute for isEnabled

Tags: acumatica

Could me please if it is possible to check the attribute for what state it is in now?
For example:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<MyQuery.value>(linkCache, linkInfQuery, false);
```

it doesn't work, but in order to make it clearer, i want something like this

```
if(PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<MyQuery.value> == false ) 
{ .... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `PXFieldState` to read the Enabled property from your field. I think this is possible in the `FieldSelecting` event like this:

```
protected void _(Events.FieldSelecting<RSSVWorkOrderItem, RSSVWorkOrderItem.myDacField> e)
        {
            PXFieldState state = (PXFieldState) e.ReturnState;
            if (state.Enabled == true)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
```

I also recommend you take a look into the Acumatica Framework Development guide and search for the chapter *Internal and External Presentation of Values*

Comment: Thanks, I used this method, I just thought that Acumatica has the ability to check an attribute without using FieldSelecting.